# Running a jar from shell script

Tags: java, linux, shell, scripting, jar

I have a jar file named umar.jar in /root/umar/bin directory. I have a shell script file run.sh in same directory. Following is the content of run.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
"$JAVA_HOME"/bin/java -jar /root/umar/bin/umar.jar
```

Now when I run the shell script, I get the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
```

After some googling, I found (as a folk from stackoverflow mentioned) that such errors occur when the Jar was compiled with a later version of the JDK than your JRE.

Now strange thing is, if I run this command directly on shell

```
java -jar umar.jar
```

it works perfectly fine. If the jar was compiled with a later version of JDK than my JRE, it shouldn't have had run at all even from the shell.

What do you suggest?

Comment: In the shell, type 'whereis java' or 'whereis javac' and compare it with 'echo "$JAVA_HOME"'. They should tell you the paths to the JRE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

compare "java -version " and ""$JAVA_HOME"/bin/java -version"

You probably have multiple JVMs installed

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned - you're trying to use byte code compiled by the later compiler with old jvm.

Please note that if your *PATH* contains multiple java executables of different versions you can switch between them easily using *'-version'* key.

Suppose you have java5 and java6 at your *PATH* and java5 is located before java6 there. You can see that java5 is used by default then (if you execute *'java -version'* it prints corresponding information). However, you can start java6 easily using command like *'java -version:1.6 ...'* (e.g. if you execute *'java -version:1.6 -version'* you see that java6 is used).

Answer (score 0):

Export the java and jre home which you need to use in your sh file.

Run the jar using the exported java home

e.g

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/java6
export JRE_HOME=/opt/java6/jre
/opt/java6/bin/java -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -jar abc.jar $1
```